# Replace Python object with Mock object when running simulator

Tags: python, mocking

I create Mail client that working with Gmail.

When I working in my development environment I have no internet access.

So, I created Mock object that instead of sending the mail to google is write it to local folder.

It looks something like:

```
Class GmailSender(object):
    def Send(title,body....):
        """ Send mail to gmail """

Class MockGmailSender(object):
    def Send(title,body....):
        """ Write to file """
```

Now all my code looks like:

```
Gmail = GmailSender()
if Simulator:
    Gmail = MockGmailSender()
```

This is awful.

I searching after module that let my replace the GmailSender object with my Mock object when my service is loading, something like:

```
if Simulator:
    replace(GmailSender,MockGmailSender)
```

And for now on when I init GmailSender the instance will be MockGmailSender.

I would love your help

Thanks,

Nadav.

Answer (score 1):

For mocking a class, you can use mock.patch:

% python ./gmail.py

### ..

Ran 2 tests in 0.033s

```
import unittest

class GmailSender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Send(self, title, body):
        """ Send mail to gmail """
        content = "{0} with {1}".format(title, body)
        return content


class testGmail(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_send(self):
        gs = GmailSender()
        self.assertEqual("A with B", gs.Send("A", "B"))
        pass

    def test_mock_send(self):
        from mock import patch
        with patch('__main__.GmailSender') as gsmock:
            gs = GmailSender()
            gsmock.return_value.Send.return_value = 'B with A'
            self.assertEqual("B with A", gs.Send("A", "B"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```